# 不正なバイト文字をcurlなどでpostする方法

Tags: curl

ウェブアプリのテストを行いたいのですが、"\xff"などの文字をパラメータとしてpostする方法がわかりません。

このような方法はないのでしょうか?

Answer (score 7):

不正バイト入りのパラメータ文字列が保存されたファイルをデータとして指定するのはどうでしょうか？

```sh
$ echo -e 'str=\xff' > invalid_bytes.txt
$ hexdump -C invalid_bytes.txt 
00000000  73 74 72 3d ff 0a                                 |str=..|
00000006
$ curl -d @invalid_bytes.txt http://httpbin.org/post
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "str": "\ufffd"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "6", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.52.1"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

多少面倒ですが、`echo` の結果をパイプでつなぐこともできます。

```sh
$ echo -e 'str=\xff' | curl -d @- http://httpbin.org/post
```

ほぼ同じですがコマンド置換を使ってもできます。

```sh
$ curl -d "$(echo -e 'str=\xff')" http://httpbin.org/post
```

ファイルに保存する代わりにシェルの変数に保存することもできます。

```sh
$ DATA=$(echo -e '\xff') curl -d "str=${DATA}" http://httpbin.org/post
```

※ ヌル文字 (\x00) を送信しようとすると、方法によっては文字列終端として扱われてしまって上手く送信できないのでご注意ください。(文字列を `abc\x00abc` などとして実行すると違いが分かります。)

#### 参考

- [`man curl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) における `-d` / `--data` オプションの説明
- リクエスト先のURLについて: [HTTP Test server that accepts GET/Post calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725430/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- [Passing binary data to curl without using a @file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77588/211480) -- Unix & Linux